# Generic Constraints Different Per Class Methods?

Tags: c#

I am making (for study purposes) a linked list class with data of type

```
public class MyLinkedList<T> : IEnumerable<MyLinkedListNode<T>>
```

For working with just linked list, I don't have to impose any constraint on T. But I would like to add a Sort method to this linked list and for this method I need T to be IComparable at least. Is there any way to tighten the constraint for this method? Or do I have to go and implement this as static method outside of the class?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with implementing it as a static method, especially since you can make that an extension method, so it would appear as if it was a regular method on `MyLinkedList`. For more flexibility, however, consider (also) supplying an instance `Sort` method that takes an `IComparer<T>` rather than demand that `T` itself be `IComparable`. For many types there is no one right way to sort them, even if there is an obvious default way to sort them.

Comment: Thanks, IComparer<T> is probably the best way to go. After I posted the question I realized that normal List<T> also does not demand T to be IComparable for Sort so after a bit of exploring I have arrived at the same conclusion.